# Reordering an array, moving all strings that contain an underscore to the bottom

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to move the strings that contain an underscore `_` to the bottom of my array. I'm assuming `usort()` is the best way but not sure how to do this in the most efficient way. Let's say my array is `'1','34_1','35_1','36_1','7','41_4','38_5','5','41_5','44_5','45_5'`

```
usort(['1','34_1','35_1','36_1','7','41_4','38_5','5','41_5','44_5','45_5'], function (){...});
```

**UPDATE:** I think I found a way to do it:

```
$myarray = ['1','34_1','35_1','36_1','7','41_4','38_5','5','41_5','44_5','45_5'];

function sortem($myarray) {
    foreach ($myarray as $index=>$item)
    {
        if (preg_match('/^_+$/', $item))
        {
            unset($myarray[$index]);
            $myarray[$index] = $item;               
        }
    }
}
usort($myarray, "sortem");
$tagsuri = array_reverse($tagsuri);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: what's is your excepted output???

Comment: I've updated my thinking. I would like the strings that contain an underscore to be last, the order doesn't matter to me. example output: ['8','7','41_7','55_8','32_7']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you could find a way to `usort()` but a quick way to do this would just be to split the array into two, then combine them back:

```
<?php
$myarray = array('1','34_1','35_1','36_1','7','41_4','38_5','5','41_5','44_5','45_5');

foreach($myarray as $value) {
    # Put all numbers into one array, underscored into a second
    if(strpos($value,'_') !== false)
        $strArr[]   =   $value;
    else
        $numArr[]   =   $value;
}
# Sort both arrays
# You'll probably want to do checks to see that they are not empty first
asort($strArr);
asort($numArr);
# Combine arrays
print_r(array_merge($numArr,$strArr));
```

**Gives you:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 34_1
    [4] => 35_1
    [5] => 36_1
    [6] => 38_5
    [7] => 41_4
    [8] => 41_5
    [9] => 44_5
    [10] => 45_5
)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I run array_filter() on the array before this to remove blank entries.

Comment: I found one issue with this. It does not work if the array has values that all have or do not have underscores. Example `'1','2','3'` or `'1_34','2_45','33_1'`

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant by doing checks